# How to crawl recursive structures using Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

Given a tree like structure, and 
an operation to fetch the children
of a node, e.g:

```
typealias NodeReference = URL 

data class Node(
     val data:Data,
     val childrenList:List<NodeReference>)

suspend fun resolve(nodeRef:NodeReference) : Node
```

Do you know a blueprint to implement a crawler 
function having the signature

```
fun nodeList(rootNode:NodeReference) : List<Node> = 
    runBlocking(...) {
      ...
    }
```

returning all nodes of the tree using Kotlin coroutines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem efficiently, you should:

1. Resolve `rootRef: NodeReference` to get a `rootNode: Node`
2. Recursively asynchronously call `nodeList` method for all `children` of the `rootNode`
3. Await for the results
4. Merge the results and add the `rootNode` to them

Here is how you can do it:

```
suspend fun nodesList(rootRef: NodeReference): List<Node> = coroutineScope {
    val rootNode = resolve(rootRef) // 1
    rootNode.childrenList
        .map { async { nodesList(it) } } // 2
        .awaitAll() // 3
        .flatten() + rootNode // 4
}
```

---

If you want to use the current thread to execute `nodesList`, you can do it as follows:

```
fun nodesListBlocking(rootRef: NodeReference): List<Node> = runBlocking { nodesList(rootRef) }
```

Comment: A problem that I see with this is that there's no control on the maximum number concurrent coroutines launched. Each coroutine maps to a network call and the number of launched coroutines rises exponentially through the children fan-out. Coroutines may be lightweight, but this can quickly reach millions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In this case, you can wait before each `async` call until there is enough memory available to launch one more coroutine. Alternatively, you can use [Semaphore](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-semaphore/) to limit the maximum number of coroutines, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58429987/10536125).

Comment: Yes, I'd go with the semaphore approach. You can't rely on `Runtime.freeMemory()` and memory may not be the scarcest resource, it would more likely be the network.

Comment: Using the approach with `Semaphore` under recursion you should not put it directly under async like this: `async { semaphore.withPermit { nodeList() }}`. Because nodeList is branching and may easily bring you to a deadlock, when all the coroutines just wait for results that cannot be delivered without free threads. Instead, in the above example the semaphore wrap should just be put INTO `resolve()`, i.e. around a non-recursive and finite code block that guarantees releasing a semaphore.