# Limit the number of coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code:

```
 val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    val data = FileOutputStream(File("data/data.json"))
    val context = newFixedThreadPoolContext(nThreads = 1)
    val requestSemaphore = Semaphore(1)
    val hitsSemaphore = Semaphore(3)
    for (town in ExternalData.fetchTowns("31")) {
        logger.info("Handling town " + town.code)
        val elements : Flow = ElasticSearchDataFetcher.fetchDataForTown(town.code)
        val jobs = elements.map {
            hitsSemaphore.withPermit {
                async {

                    logger.info("Handling mutation with ID {} for town {}", it.second.id, town.code)
                    data.write((mapper.writeValueAsBytes(Converter.convert(it.second))))
                    data.write("\n".toByteArray())
                }
            }
        }.toList()
        jobs.forEach { it.await() }
```

It fetches a list of towns (around 200 towns) and for each of them it fetches data from `ElasticSearch`. There's about 420k records for all the towns.

When I ran this I ran out of memory (I only have 6G). My idea is to limit the number of coroutines, but I didn't find any way to do it. I tested the solutions of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428584/limiting-the-maximum-number-of-coroutines-that-can-run-in-a-scope), but they don't seem to work in my case.

How can I limit the number of created coroutines or how can avoid OOM?

Comment: Perhaps fetch N towns at the time, persist the data in a DB (room?) then fetch the next, batch, do the same, etc. `N` can be any number from 1 to whatever you think is safe given the size of the data. ALso `Converter.convert` could be allocating stuff (don't know). Also `.toList()` at the end is making a list wth ALL the elements... so perhaps don't do that like so?

Comment: You can control the level of concurrency if you use a flow and `flatMapMerge`.